# Magical Record - Work with 2 models Coredata or more

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Can I work with 2 models coredata or more. 
 In my app I use 2 models which are packages(tables: package, exercise, test, question) and dictionary(table: word) to store app info. I already find place where have info of `managedObjectModel` to change name of it but I can't find anything. 
 What should I do with this case?

Answer (score 0):

MagicalRecord simply provides helpers to making the default stack easy. It also does not prevent you from going with alternate stack configurations. You can have a second managed object model, and there is a helper for it, but only the first will be the "default" model. You will have to manage the second model yourself. It also means you can create extra persistent stores that are connected to this model.